# Spring batch with multiple main and scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduler

I am working on a Spring Batch project that has two Main classes with `@SpringBootApplication` in it. I also have to use the `@Scheduler` and associate it only with one Main class. But the issue here is no matter which class I run, the scheduler is getting executed. Snippets below,

`MainApp1.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MainApp1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(MainApp1.class, args);
    }
}
```

`MainApp2.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication

    public class MainApp2{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(MainApp2.class, args);
        }
    }
```

`Scheduler.java`

```
@Configuration
public class TmsBatchSenderScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void myScheduler() {

    }
}
```

I think what's happening here is the scheduler is getting created for both mains because of the `@Configuration` annotation. Is there a way to achieve this? I want the scheduler to run only when the `MainApp1` is run.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you run the app? Is it with `java -jar yourapp.jar`? The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` should fail in the `repackage` phase if it finds two main classes in your project and you would need to specify which one to use (See how in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html#Repackaging_an_application). Have you tried to move each app to a separate package (See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code)?

Comment: Haven't done that much yet. Currently I am running them from STS separately.

Comment: ok in that case, try to put each app in its own package.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Well in that case, either exclude `TmsBatchSenderScheduler` in your  `MainApp2` or use Spring profiles.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to exclude a class ?

Comment: Try `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class)` in the class where you don't need scheduling. I really recommend creating a spring boot app for each app, so much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things.

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. This is a temporary work around solution. We will be migrating soon to that architecture. And unfortunately we are currently using SpringBoot version 1.5 :( So, no `TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration`. Any other alternative please?

Comment: I also tried adding `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=TmsBatchSenderScheduler.class)` It did not work. Got an exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes`